# remove all the special character In start of a string using PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

How to remove all the special character In start(First Letter Should Be Alphanumeric) of a string using PHP ? Please

$String = "+&,Hello+{+ +$world";

After remove all special character in start of a string

The string should become  "Hello+{+ +$world"

Help me.

Comment: Tell me the matching URL PLease ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will replace everything in the beginning which is not alphanumeric:

```
preg_replace('/^([^a-zA-Z0-9])*/', '', $string);
```

UPDATE:

If you need to trim non-alphanumeric characters both in the start and in the end of a string use this:

```
<?php

$string = "++&5Hello ++f s world6f++&ht6__)  ";

echo preg_replace('/(^([^a-zA-Z0-9])*|([^a-zA-Z0-9])*$)/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Error display as below                                                                                      Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 16 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 5

Comment: Tell me also How to remove all the special character in start and end of each string using PHP ? Please .

Comment: @soavahaf Answer updated to answer your request. I must point out though that your original question explicitly asks for the start of a string in the title.

Answer (score 2):

try to use `trim` for more information see this http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

for remove from start of string you can use `ltrim` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php

for remove from end of string you can use `rtrim` 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

code for Your sample

```
$String = "+&,Hello+{+ +$world";
echo ltrim($String,"&+,");
```

you can add more character in ltrim for remove from first of string

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function string_cleaner($result)
{
    $result = strip_tags($result);
    $result = preg_replace('/[^\da-z]/i', ' ', $result);
    $result = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $result); 
    $result = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', ' ', $result);
    $result = preg_replace('|-+|', ' ', $result);
    $result = preg_replace('/_+/', ' ', $result);
    $result = preg_replace('/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i','',$result);
    $result = preg_replace('/[^%A-Za-z0-9 _-]/', ' ', $result);
    $result = preg_replace('/^\W+|\W+$/', '', $result);
    $result = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $result);
    $result = trim($result, ' ');
    return $result;
}
?>

<?php
echo string_cleaner($content);
?>
```

Comment: try with this $result = preg_replace('/^\W+|\W+$/', '', $result);

Comment: What is this code exactly doing? Why would you need so many different regular expressions ?

Comment: @Devan your regex in the comments would not replace underscores.

Comment: you can add this line $result = str_replace('_', ' ', $result); or use this $result = preg_replace('/_+/', ' ', $result);

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $String);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use trim - it's an in-built function:
    http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Answer (score 0):

I think using ltrim will be more useful as you want to remove in starting of the string : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php

Comment: Can you share the example what you are looking for ?

Comment: $String = "+&,Hello+{+ +$world";    After removing special character from start of a string the string would be print like "Hello+{+ +$world"

Comment: If you have the list of special character , you can call $trimmed = ltrim($text, "{your special charter}"); runing in a loop for all the special characters . Remember to use the $trimmed variable for passing to next loop.