# remove all the special character in start and end of each string using PHP

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

How to remove all the special character in start and end of each string using PHP ? Tell me How ?

Example Code :

```
$string ="_$#+Hello(+- $^#World2013@!%=+";
```

After Remove All special character from the string start and end position .The string would be print as below :

```
$string ="Hello(+- $^#World2013";
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: With regular expressions, check here http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Comment: Maybe `:cntrl:` works. Have to test it.

Comment: Are the characters random, or are they always the same characters?

Comment: Why has this question been upvoted?? Define "special characters" (among the 50 or so other things you need to explain in order to come up with a decent regex), as I would have thought your result still contains plenty of "special characters".

Comment: @Sepster He wants to remove all special chars (not letters or numbers) from the start and end of his string. So if he has `$!!Hey_You!`, he'd get `Hey_You` back.

Comment: `$string=trim($string, $my_special_characters);` should do it and you choose what those "Speial Characters" are

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove all the special character In start of a string using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612431/remove-all-the-special-character-in-start-of-a-string-using-php)

Comment: @Waygood Why not post that as an (the) answer?  It's purpose built for this use-case.

Comment: @Prisoner Fair call.  It's actually a pretty good specification in its brevity.  I glossed over it thinking "no regex can be defined well in so few lines".  It's not concrete, but actually pretty good example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string ="_$#+Hello(+- $^#World2013@!%=+";

$sub_string = preg_replace("/^([^a-zA-Z0-9])*/", "", $string,1);
$sub_string = strrev(preg_replace("/^([^a-zA-Z0-9])*/", "",strrev($sub_string),1));

var_dump($sub_string); // string(21) "Hello(+- $^#World2013"
```

Comment: @Sepster that is true, although you are required to list every possible special char. His is a blacklist, mines whitelist.

Answer (score 7):

Trim will remove characters from the beginning and end of the string.

```
$string ="_$#+Hello(+- $^#World2013@!%=+";

$my_special_characters='_$#@!%=+';
$string=trim($string, $my_special_characters);
```

You can update the $my_special_characters variable with whatever you require.

Comment: +1 Nice one.  If there's something purpose built for the job, use it (especially when it helps avoid regex!) ;-)